# How to create US state choropleth map

Tags: data

I have a value associated with each US state (let's pretend it's the average temperature in January for each state). I want to display this data as a heat map of the United States. To be clear, it would be a map of the US with each state having a color from a color gradient that corresponds to a quantitative value. I don't know what this plot type is called, so I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in MATLAB or another program, but does anyone know an easy way to do this? I have a vector of data (of length 50) and just need to make a US map plot.

Comment: If you're willing to use R, the maps package should do the trick! https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Plotly in Python [provides a nice solution](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/):

```python
!pip install chart_studio
from chart_studio import plotly as py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]

df['text'] = df['state'] + '<br>' +\
    'Beef '+df['beef']+' Dairy '+df['dairy']+'<br>'+\
    'Fruits '+df['total fruits']+' Veggies ' + df['total veggies']+'<br>'+\
    'Wheat '+df['wheat']+' Corn '+df['corn']

data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = df['code'],
        z = df['total exports'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = df['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            )
        ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "Millions USD"
        )
    ) ]

layout = dict(
        title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
            showlakes = True,
            lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        ),
    )
    
fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )

url = py.plot( fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map' )
```

[image]

Comment: It seems plotly got deprecated and with the latest version this no longer works

Comment: This solution is quite old so few changes are required. plotply.plotly module got deprecated so we need to install chart studio with `pip install chart_studio` or use `apt-get`. Then use `from chart_studio import plotly as py`

Answer (score 5):

There are [many ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=choropleth+map+r) to plot [choropleth maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) in R. Here's another one that uses the popular grammar of graphics library ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
choro <- left_join(
  map_data("state"), 
  USArrests %>% 
    add_rownames("region") %>% 
    mutate(region=tolower(region))
)
ggplot(choro, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = Assault)) + 
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, any way to add Alaska and Hawaii though?

Comment: Hmm like `ggplot() + borders("world", region = "usa") + borders("state") + coord_quickmap()`?

Answer (score 2):

R, with [googlevis package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html), also provides great solution (interactive html map):

```
require(datasets)
states <- data.frame(state.name, state.x77)
GeoStates <- gvisGeoChart(states, "state.name", "Illiteracy",
                          options=list(region="US", 
                                       displayMode="regions", 
                                       resolution="provinces",
                                       width=600, height=400))
plot(GeoStates)
```

[image]